# Why does a definition of macro containing multi raster column n/.style fail in \tcbset of tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I make up a macro `\allcw` which contains some definition of raster column width style like this:

```
raster column 1/.style={width=2em},
raster column 2/.style={width=6em},
raster column 3/.style={width=12em}
```

Please see my code below.
But it does not be compiled? What's wrong with my code?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\columnwidthlist{2em,6em,12em,}
\newcounter{step}
\newcommand{\allcw}{%
  \setcounter{step}{0}
  \def\mystore{}
  \foreach \x in \columnwidthlist {
    \stepcounter{step}
    \IfStrEq{\x}{}{}
      {%
       \xappto\mystore{
          raster column \thestep/.style=\{width=\x\},
        }
      }
    }
  \tcbset{cwall/.style={code={\pgfkeysalsofrom{\mystore}}}}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3,raster force size=false,code={\allcw},cwall]
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess ` \foreach \x in columnwidthlist ` doesn't work because `columnwidthlist` is just a string, not a list. If you replace that by `\foreach \x in \columnwidthlist `, there is still an error (perhaps unrelated), but the loop works.

Comment: Sorry, that is a  mistake in writing which I have just correct. The code still can not be compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to add backslash (and remove `cwall`, which is not defined in your example).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\columnwidthlist{2em,6em,12em,}
\newcounter{step}
\newcommand{\allcw}{%
  \setcounter{step}{0}
  \def\mystore{}
  \foreach \x in \columnwidthlist {
    \stepcounter{step}
    \IfStrEq{\x}{}{}
      {%
       \xappto\mystore{
          raster column \thestep/.style=\{width=\x\},
        }
      }
    }
  \tcbset{cwall/.style={code={\pgfkeysalsofrom{\mystore}}}}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3,raster force size=false] % ,cwall
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your real question: analogous things have been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175803/121799) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175808/121799), for instance. So you might do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{step}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tcbset{set width/.code args={#1}{\stepcounter{step}
\pgfkeysalso{/tcb/raster column \thestep/.style/.expanded={width=#1}}
},
set widths/.code={\setcounter{step}{0}
\pgfkeys{/tcb/set width/.list/.expanded={#1}}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\tcbset{myset/.style args={raster column #1/.style={width=#2}}}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3,raster force
size=false,set widths={2em,6em,12em}]
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
\end{tcbitemize}
```

[image]

Comment: But the cwall/.style is what I need to have each column width modified. And I define this style in my code as like this: \tcbset{cwall/.style={code={\pgfkeysalsofrom{\mystore}}}}

Comment: @lyl I guess you need to explain better what you want to do. Where is your command `\allcw` called that will define the style?

Comment: @ marmot  I just correct my code and \allcw is called in option part of the tcbitemize. What I want is to set each column width by my self, 2em, 6em ,12em in my example.

Comment: @lyl I added one possibility, most likely there is a more elegant way based on `/.list`....

Comment: @ marmot Thank you very much for your help. And could you please tell me what's the meaning "\globaldefs=1\relax"?

Comment: @lyl I replaced it by a cleaner proposal.

Comment: @ marmot but I think {2em, 6em, 12em} is better than {1/2em,2/6em,3/12em}

Comment: @lyl I modified the version accordingly.

Comment: Many thanks for your patience! I find your first version of solution is more understandable.Could you tell me which package define the macro \typeout and its function in this example. Another question,  why is \relax needed after \globaldefs=1?

Comment: @lyl ***DON'T*** (note boldface italic all caps) use `\globaldefs` if you don't precisely know what it's about. It's ***VERY*** dangerous.

Comment: @egreg More dangerous than pineapple on a pizza? ;-)