# How to overalap textbox in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I want to draw the following flowchart in latex (tikz package).
Can someone please help in doing this job please[image]

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Raaja i tried to update the following flowchart http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/flowchart/

Comment: You might have more responses if you show what you tried (I mean the code updated by you, not the original source code from the link you gave)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous ways to draw such things, here is one.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[data/.style={minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw},
font=\sffamily,
% cf https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175803/121799
apply data style to row/.style={row #1/.append style={nodes={data}}}]
 \matrix (mat) [matrix of nodes,column sep=0.2cm,row sep=2mm,
 apply data style to row/.list={2,3,5,6}
 ]{
 Load datasets & \hspace*{1cm} & Load datasets \\
 Data 1 & & Data 1 \\
 Data 2 & & Data 2 \\[5em]
  & & Load datasets\\
  & & Data 1 \\
  & & Data 2 \\
 };
 \foreach \X [count=\Z] in {(mat-1-1)(mat-3-1),(mat-1-3)(mat-3-3),(mat-4-3)(mat-6-3)}
 {\node[fit=\X,draw,inner ysep=6mm,yshift=-2.5mm,inner xsep=2mm] (F-\Z) {};
  \node[fill=white,draw] (L-\Z) at (F-\Z.south) {Result=Tuple};}
 \draw[-latex,blue] (F-1) -- (F-2);
 \draw[-latex,blue] (L-2) -- (F-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your comment...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[data/.style={minimum height=1cm,minimum width=4cm,draw},
font=\sffamily,
% cf https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175803/121799
datamat/.style={matrix of nodes,column sep=0.2cm,row sep=2mm,
anchor=north,inner sep=3mm,
nodes={data},row 1/.append style={nodes={draw=none}},draw,
label={[anchor=center,draw,fill=white,name=label]below:#1}}]
\matrix (mat1) [datamat=Tuple]{
 Load datasets \\
 Data 1 \\
 Data 2 \\[1em]
 \\
 };
\matrix (mat2) [datamat=Tuple2,below right=0cm and 2cm of mat1.north east]{
 Load datasets \\
 Data 1 \\
 Data 2 \\
 Data 3 \\[1em]
 \\
 };
\matrix (mat3) [datamat=Tuple3,below=1cm of mat2]{
 Load datasets \\
 Data 1 \\
 Data 2 \\
 Data 3 \\
 Data 4 \\[1em]
 \\
 };
 \draw[-latex,blue,thick] (mat1) -- (mat1-|mat2.west);
 \draw[-latex,blue,thick] ([xshift=5mm]mat2.south west) -- ([xshift=5mm]mat3.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you solution is ok, but may be i was not to precise. Some boxes may contain different number of su-boxes (data1, data2, etc) and differents title (result=tuple). So please, how i can update you solution

Comment: @bib I added a second proposal...